# Does Tree implementation in Java hold the entire next Node v/s just holding address in C

Tags: java, c, pointers, object

Notice how in the C version, only the address of the node, that is, Node* is saved, whereas, in the Java version, the entire Node is saved.

Does this mean that the Java code to run occupies more memory as compared to the C code?

C version

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>

typedef struct node
{
 int data;
 struct node* left;
 struct node* right;
}Node;
Node* root;

void inorder(Node* node)
{
 if(node == NULL)
  return;

 inorder(node->left);
 printf("%d ",node->data);
 inorder(node->right);
}

void insert(int data)
{
printf("inside insert, data == %d",data);    

 Node* node = malloc(sizeof(Node));
 node->data = data;
 node->left = NULL;
 node->right = NULL;

 if(root == NULL)
 {
     printf("inserting %d as root",node->data);
     root = node;
 }
 else
 { 
  Node* trav = root;
  Node* pretrav = root;
  while(trav != NULL)
  {
   pretrav = trav;
   if(node->data < trav->data)
    trav = trav->left;
   else
    trav = trav->right;
  }

  if(node->data < pretrav->data)
  {
      printf("inserting %d to the left of %d",node->data, pretrav->data);
   pretrav->left = node;   
  }
  else
  {
      printf("inserting %d to the right of %d",node->data, pretrav->data);
   pretrav->right = node;   
  }
 }  
}

int main(void)
{
 int a[] = {10,5,15,1,20,100};
 int i = 0; 

 for(i = 0;i<sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]);i++)
 {
  insert(a[i]);
  printf("\n");
 }

 inorder(root);

 return 0;
}
```

Java version

```
package lastcommon;

public class TreeExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Tree tree = new Tree();
        tree.insert(10);
        tree.insert(5);
        tree.insert(15);
        tree.insert(1);
        tree.insert(20);
        tree.insert(100);

        System.out.println("Printing inorder... ");
        tree.inorder(tree.root);
    }

}

class Node
{
    int data;
    Node left;
    Node right;

    public Node() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        left = right = null;
    }
}

class Tree
{
    Node root;

    public Tree() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        root = null;
    }

    void inorder(Node node)
    {
        if(node == null)
            return;

        inorder(node.left);
        System.out.println(node.data);
        inorder(node.right);
    }

    void preorder(Node node)
    {
        if(node == null)
            return;

        System.out.println(node.data);
        preorder(node.left);
        preorder(node.right);
    }

    void postorder(Node node)
    {
        if(node == null)
            return;

        postorder(node.left);
        postorder(node.right);
        System.out.println(node.data);
    }

    void insert(int data)
    {
        Node node = new Node();
        node.data = data;

        if(root == null)
        {
            root = node;
            return;
        }

        Node trav = root;
        Node pretrav = root;
        while( trav != null )
        {
            pretrav = trav;
            if(node.data < trav.data)
            {
                trav = trav.left;
            }
            else
            {
                trav = trav.right;
            }
        }

        if(node.data < pretrav.data)
            pretrav.left = node;
        else
            pretrav.right = node;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java uses references in very much the same way that C uses pointers.  They are related but you cannot manipulate references like you can manipulate pointers, making them safer to use (your program less likely to crash).

A reference is created every time `new` is invoked.  Look inside the `insert` method and you can see that `new Node(...)` is called there, creating a new object and returns a reference to the new object.

Whenever you use such a reference in your own code, it is only the "pointer" and not the whole object which is saved in the variable.

Comment: Thanks a lot for clarifying, so do you mean to say that, when the new keyword is used, it creates a new instance of the class, and returns the address of the newly created instance? And NOT return the entire newly allocated block, as I assumed?

Comment: Yes.   This is not intuitive.

Comment: Thanks again, I was initially confused, since in C, node.data means that node is the actual block of memory, and only node->data is the block corresponding to the address that is held by node. But in Java, node.data itself is the block at the address that is held by node.

Answer (score 0):

One of the low-level powers of C is the memory management. When you use a pointer, you use a memory address. In that way you can charge little pieces of memory, instead of the java-way (charging the entire object, with all his standard methods, heritage...).

So, most of time, C gives you the power to set a lesser size of memory at running time. In the other hand, Java use to allocate bigger blocks of memory (bassed on objects), but it's more confortable, safer (as they said up there), and let's you think about "real-world" problems.